# Is this a valid use of forEach()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Adding each of the items in an array to the result. This is what I tried.

```
function sum(array) {
  var result = 0;
    result += forEach(array);
  return result;
}
```

The way I know that works is such

```
function sum(numbers) {
  var total = 0;
  forEach(numbers, function (number) {
    total += number;
  });
  return total;
}
show(sum([1, 10, 100]));
```

Comment: That's what `reduce` does: `[1,2,3].reduce(function(a,b){return a+b},0); //=> 6`

Comment: Unless you have `forEach` defined somewhere that won't work.. Did you mean to use `Array.prototype.forEach` as in `[1,2,3].forEach(fn)`? Or are you using a library that provides this function?

Comment: Now that everyone mentioned it, I reread Eloquent Javascript again and forgot it was defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct.

```
function sum(numbers) {
  var total = 0;
  numbers.forEach(function (number) {
    total += number;
  });
  return total;
}
show(sum([1, 10, 100]));
```

Your use of `total` as a closure to aggregate the result is perfectly fine.

I don't know what `show` does, but I'm guessing you have it defined elsewhere. Also note that `Array.forEach` may not be available on older browsers (IE8 comes to mind).

Answer (score 0):

The `forEach` function is not a component of the Javascript language, so it's impossible for us to say for sure.

That being said, it is highly unlikely that the function works in such a way that `result += forEach(array)` would work. (It would have to somehow guess that it should add together all its arguments and return the result, which would *only* work for this use case.)

---

For what it's worth, a vaguely similar construct exists in Perl:

```
$result += $_ foreach @array;
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` does not exist as a function in JavaScript. 
You can use `for (var prop in obj)` as similar construct, but **only** for objects (`{}`) and **not** for arrays (`[]`). Here you will probablly have to use something like

```
var sum=0,len=arr.length
for (var i=0;i<len;i++) sum+=arr[i];
```